# How to perfectly center text on an inline-display block with no definitive height correctly in this very standard yet unanswered way?

Tags: html, css, centering

I've managed to use the preceding `<span>` method of centering items, which is all well, except for one little tiny issue illustrated in this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJFzu.jpg

how do i fix this? here is my css and html:

```
* {
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   text-align: center;
 }

 @font-face {
   font-family: myfirstfont;
   src: url(century-gothic.ttf);
 }

 body,
 html {
   height: 100%;
   white-space: -0.125em;
   background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 }

 #wrapper {
   height: inherit;
   min-height: 100%;
 }

 .O1-3 {
   color: white;
   width: 100%;
   height: 33.5%;
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: myfirstfont;
 }

 div span {
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 div a {
   font-size: 35px;
   display: inline-block;
   font-style: italic;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 @media screen and (min-width:600px) {
   .O1-3 {
     height: inherit;
     width: 33.3%;
   }
 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="O1-3" id="one">
      <span></span>
      <a id="n-textonly">Luis Rojas</a>
    </div>
    <div class="O1-3" id="two">
      <span></span>
      <a id="c-textonly">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="O1-3" id="three">
      <span></span>
      <a id="rw-textonly">Recent Work</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple methods of centering in css, but without a definitive height, you're confined to a just few methods. Here are a few techniques I put together and commented out for you to take a look at: https://jsfiddle.net/73mtxgcc/3/

There are other techniques such as using `flex` or using `display:table`, but I find those, personally, either sloppy or not quite supported enough. As well, if you have something relative to the window, then you can always also use

```
.element{
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

with `.element` being the parent of the content you'd like to center.

If you have any more questions, or if you need any further clarifications, then please don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 0):

You want to give all three columns the same padding with auto width, to get the text to be evenly spaced, then the wrapper centers the entire group. You get same amount of space on each side of the group, and then equal spacing in-between, so the center column ends up not being in the exact center of the page, but it has a very balanced visual effect for the page as a whole. You still need some adjustments with break-points though, I added one.

```
#wrapper {
  width: auto;
  height: inherit;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.O1-3 {
  padding: 1em;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  height: 33.5%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: myfirstfont;
}

@media screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .O1-3 {
    padding: 2em;
    height: inherit;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width:1000px) {
  .O1-3 {
    padding: 5em;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to formatting HTML content with CSS, you should really use Flexbox. It is becoming really popular and is widely supported. In the code below, I have added a display: flex; property to your #wrapper. This creates a flex-box out of the wrapper. From there, I added a flex-direction of row, which will automatically format it's three child elements horizontally. In the media query, I have changed the flex-direction property so that the wrapper's child elements are formatted vertically.

-- Hope this helps.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  * {
   padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
   text-align: center;
 }

 @font-face {
   font-family: myfirstfont;
   src: url(century-gothic.ttf);
 }

 body,
 html {
   height: 100%;
   white-space: -0.125em;
   background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
 }

 #wrapper {
   height: inherit;
   min-height: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
 }

 .O1-3 {
   color: white;
   width: 100%;
   height: 33.5%;
   text-align: center;
   font-family: myfirstfont;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }

 div span {
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 div a {
   font-size: 35px;
   display: inline-block;
   font-style: italic;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width:600px) {
   .O1-3 {
     height: inherit;
     width: 100%
     margin: auto;
   }
   #wrapper {
     flex-direction: column;
   }
 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="O1-3" id="one">
      <span></span>
      <a id="n-textonly">Luis Rojas</a>
    </div>
    <div class="O1-3" id="two">
      <span></span>
      <a id="c-textonly">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="O1-3" id="three">
      <span></span>
      <a id="rw-textonly">Recent Work</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```